# Error without new operator

Tags: javascript, constructor

I was reading [this example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promisifying-xmlhttprequest) on `Promise`. I realized that `Error` constructor is not called with `new` operator. Why does it work, then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because [the specification says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-error-objects) that the constructor function should check how it is called, and if it isn't called with `new` it should call itself with `new` and return that.

> The Error constructor is the %Error% intrinsic object and the initial value of the Error property of the global object. When Error is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initializes a new Error object. Thus the function call Error(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Error(…) with the same arguments.

An example implementation of that in JS might look like:

```
function MyC(foo, bar) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyC)) {
    return new MyC(foo, bar);
  }
  this.foo = foo;
  this.bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: From ES6 we can use `new.target`. `new.target !== MyC`